# Update secondary tiles in push notifications

Tags: windows-phone-8

I had worked on a sample and i had updated the secondary tiles using tile notifications from service. I had included "id" in xml content of the tile notification

the particular tile was updated it was fine. I had a doubt that

1. can we update the secondary tile and application tile at the same time?
2. If user does not pin the secondary tile then the update notification of particular tile is wasted?